# Understanding loop function made of setTimeout and clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am making a simple fadeIn/fadeOut loop animation which uses `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`. Here's my code so far:

HTML:

```
<p><span>loading...</span></p>
<a href="#" id="btn">STOP</a>
```

Javascript(jQuery1.9.1):

```
var _timer;
var _timerArr = [];

var loaderBlink = function() {
    $('p').find('span').fadeTo(200,.4).fadeTo(200,1,function() {
        _timer = setTimeout(function() { loaderBlink() }, 200);
        _timerArr.push(_timer);
        //console.log('loading...');
    });
};

var clearTimer = function() {
    $.each(_timerArr, function(i,val) {
        clearTimeout(val);
        console.log(val);
    });

    $('#btn').remove();
    $('p').fadeOut('fast');

    return false;
};

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    clearTimer();
});

loaderBlink();
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/MW9E8/

The problem is that even though I pushed all timers into an array in order to clear them all afterwards by clicking STOP button, sometime timer won't stop and just keeps going on.

Probably I don't fully understand the concept of `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`. I need some solution to this and help in understanding those two functions.

Comment: edited the code little bit.

Comment: Are there any specific circumstances where it doesn't work? Tried it a few times without any problems.

Comment: Matt it works, but if you look at the console the timeouts are still running. I would suggest using setInterval instead of timeout. So you have just one element to stop. example coming soon :)

Comment: If you click the button in the first 400ms, the timers haven't yet been attached, so `clearTimer` does nothing.

Comment: @smb, Eric both of you guys rocks! Yes, why I didnt think of setInterval ver. instead. For the looper I will try to use the setInterval func. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a setIntevall version:

Edit: it works well, but you have to wrap the timer with your function loaderBlink(); again, deleted it by mistake, not enough coffee yet.

```
var _timer;

_timer = setInterval(function () {
            $('p').find('span').fadeTo(200,.4).fadeTo(200,1);
            console.log('loading...');
        }, 400);


var clearTimer = function() {
    clearInterval(_timer);

    $('#btn').remove();
    $('p').fadeOut('fast');

    return false;
};

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    clearTimer();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XHUTV/2/

Comment: This should be `setInterval(..., 400)`, since each cycle does two 200ms operations

Comment: you're correct, i didn't care about timings just want to show the oportunity of using setInterval

Answer (score 1):

Saving a reference to all timers in an array doesn't make much sense -- timers aren't running consecutively so it would be enough to store only the most recent timer in a single array. You only need to stop the last one, everything else has already stopped.

I suspect the timer won't stop when you click at some point when the animation is running so the button stops all timers except the one that hasn't started yet because the animation queue starts it only when the animation has stopped.

Anyway, this would actually be easier and more reliable to make without a timer.

```
var blink = true;

var loaderBlink = function() {
    if( blink ) {
        $('p').find('span').delay( 200 ).fadeTo(200,.4).fadeTo(200,1,function() {
            loaderBlink();
            console.log('loading...');
        });
    }
};

$('#btn').on('click', function() {    
    blink = false;
    $(this).remove();
    $('p').stop().fadeOut('fast');

    return false;
});

loaderBlink();
```

The operation is just slightly different than the original code: the 200 ms delay is at the beginning of the animation loop instead of after it, but I assume it's not a problem. `.stop()` makes sure the loop doesn't start again.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WAprd/17/

Comment: This is still wrong - If there are two `p span`s, it'll create an exponentially forking tree of `loaderBlink` calls.

Comment: @Eric I assume the selector is different in the actual version and `p span` is just for demo purposes. You'd think the OP would have mentioned it if that was a problem.

Comment: My point is that this will fail if the selector matches more than one element.

Comment: Fair enough. @smb's version is probably cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to this problem is a little wrong - as you see you defined the time to be in 200ms - this time is a very short time and before the code is get to react your click the next timer will go ahead so sometime it's working sometimes it isn't.
also saving all the interval_ids in an array does not make any sense since setTimeout only happens once (as opposed to setInterval). what you need to do is use a flag and turn off the single timer id:  http://jsfiddle.net/MW9E8/2/

```
var _timer;
var _timerArr = [];
var fading;

var loaderBlink = function() {
    if(fading){
        $('p').find('span').fadeTo(200,.4).fadeTo(200,1,function() {
            interval_id = setTimeout(function() { loaderBlink() }, 200);
           // _timerArr.push(_timer);
            console.log('loading...');
        });
    }
};

var clearTimer = function() {
    /*
    $.each(_timerArr, function(i,val) {

        console.log(val);
    });
    */    
    clearTimeout(interval_id);
    fading = false;

   // $('#btn').remove();
   // $('p').fadeOut('fast');

    return false;
};

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    clearTimer();
});

fading = true;
loaderBlink();
```

Comment: now I clearly understand difference between interval and timeout.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery for the animation, you might as well keep to using jQuery for everything else... no need to mix in `setIntervals` and `setTimeouts`:

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/QNMkp/

**markup**

```
<span id="loading">Loading...</span>

<button id="stop">Stop!</button>
```

**js**

```
$(function(){

    var fadeLoading;

    (fadeLoading = function(){
        $('#loading:not(.stopped)')
            .fadeTo(200,0.4)
            .fadeTo(200,1, fadeLoading) /// you can just loop this
        ;
    })();

    $('#stop').click(function(){
        $('#loading')
            .addClass('stopped') /// add a class to stop new fade starting
            .stop() /// stop existing animations
            .fadeTo(200,1) /// fade loading up to 100%
        ;
    });

});
```

Comment: This works fine to me. i will separately making none set/clearTimeout version of my loop animation by your solution.Thank you!